# Determining winner in game of stochastic variables with multiple iterations

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have the following question:
There are two skateboarders trying to do tricks and win points. Skateboarder $A$ can do a trick that yields him $5$ points, and works with a probability of $0.6$. If it does not work, it gives him $0$ points. Skateboarder $B$ can do the same, but his trick yields him $8$ points, with a lower probability of $0.45$. There are $10$ rounds. What player has the highest chance of winning (getting the greatest amount of points)?

I've tried three different approaches, but i'm very uncertain as to which one is correct.

**Approach 1**: **Brute force**. If there was only $1$ round, it wouldn't matter who got how many points: The only thing that would matter would be the percentages. The chance of player $A$ winning if there was one round, is the chance of his trick succeeding and his opponent's trick failing. Opposite goes for the chance of his opponent winning. Hence, it is $0.6*(1-0.45) = 0.33$ against $0.45*(1-0.6)=0.18$, so player $A$ wins. What i'm doing here is part of a very direct and general strategy to determine the chance one stochastic variable is greater than another: "Simply" sum up the probability of every combination of values from the two stochastic variables in which the value from your desired stochastic variable is greater than the value from the other one. This is easy with one round, but gets very complex when we start to do multiple rounds. With two rounds, both stochastic variables representing player $A$
and $B$ have three different possible values. For $A$: $0$, $5$, $10$, for $B$: $0, 8, 16$. Now we have to handle alot more combinations, and the percentages grow more difficult to calculate. I do feel somewhat certain that this approach is "correct", but it is incredibly unweildy. Also, i only need to determine what player has the greatest chance of winning, i dont actually need to determine *what* that chance of winning is.

**Approach 2: Simple mean**. This one is more based off of intuitive reasoning, and i know for sure that it does *not* work in the case of $1$ round. Suppose we've had alot of rounds, say a $100$. After this many rounds (iterations), approximating the points one stochastic variable has made is much more accurate. You could with some certainty say skateboarder $A$ has made around $(100*0.6)*5 + (100*0.4)*0 = 300$ points, and $B$ around $(100*0.45)*8 + (100*0.55)*0 = 360$. This approximation would not be nearly as accurate with only $2$ rounds, since in that case, the possible variation has a greater influence. I do feel with some degree of certainty that this method is "correct" if the amount of rounds is "pretty large". I know for sure that it is most certainly correct if the amount of rounds is infinite.

**Approach 3: Advanced mean**. Suppose there are $10$ rounds. As mentioned in approach 1, our stochastic variables will now have more possible values: $11$ to be specific. The variable for skateboarder $A$ for example has possible values $0, 5, 10, ... 50$ and $B$ has $0, 8, ... 80$. Due to, in this very particular case, the quite simple nature of the "original" stochastic variable, the new associated PDF's can easily be computed with a binomial distribution. Now my thinking is: We could figure out the "winner", by computing the means of these new stochastic variables, and seeing which one is greatest. The player with the greatest mean would *always* win if they did an infinite amount of these $10$-round rounds, and if he *always* wins in the infinite case, wouldn't he always have the greatest chance of winning in the finite case? This is, as noted, *incorrect* if there is only one round, since taking this mean will involve the *points* of each player, which as noted in approach 1, is not relevant if there is only one round. Very uncertain about this approach.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you define the 'win'? Most games, i.e. at least 6/10? What if there's a draw?

Comment: So you need to calculate $P(5N_A>8 N_B)$ where $N_A$ and $N_B$ are number of successes of the two players that have binomial distributions.

Comment: @Alex, i meant the win as "which player has the greatest amount of points in the end". Thought it could be derived from context, but i'll add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate $P(5N_A > 8 N_B)$, where where $N_A$ and $N_B$ are number of successes of the two players that have binomial distributions. This will look like

$P(N_B=0)P( N_A \geq 1)+P(N_B=1)P( N_A \geq 2) +P(N_B=2)P( N_A \geq 4)+\ldots $

which is a bit messy but easy to solve on computer using binomial pdf and cdf.

Alternatively you note

$P(5N_A > 8 N_B)=P(\frac{N_A}{N_B}>\frac{8}{5})$ and use the log-normal approximation for the ratio of binomials described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Binomial_distribution.